# how to filter by date with datetimefield in Django with MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

Datetimefield in MYSQL cannot be filtered by date.

```
    class Data(models.Model):
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

As docs, it could be filtered by date:

```
  qs = Data.objects.fitler(created_at__date__lte=datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))
```

It works fine with sqlite3, but it always return empty queryset with MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the date to a `datetime` object. In your case convert `'2022-01-01'` as:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_object = datetime.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")

# Then you can filter it as
qs = Data.objects.fitler(created_at__date__lte=date_object)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Yes it works. It would be best if you could give a brief explanation? In this way, __date could be omitted. I just want to filter by DATE to avoid timezone issue.

Comment: @MasZero It is because SQLite does not support built-in DateTime storage a class, but SQLite allows us to work with time types. The working is possible since the python sqlite3 module converts the datetime into the string format. And already given as string skips that job. But when it comes to MySql it supports the DateTime storage class and hence it works that way.

Comment: what if we need to group by the date? as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739328/in-django-how-to-annotategroup-by-date-from-a-datetime-field-with-mysql)