# In django, how to annotate(group by) date from a datetime field with MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

Defined as

```
class Data(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

And the requirement is to get `sum` group by `date` from `created_at` and I was using.

```
qs = Data.objects.values('created_at__date').annotate(sum=Sum('number'))
```

The above query works fine with sqlite3, but it failed with MySql. In MySql, it returns single result `<QuerySet [{'created_at__date': None, 'sum': 100}]>`

Excepted:

```
<QuerySet [
  {'created_at__date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 12), 'sum': 50}, 
  {'created_at__date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 13), 'sum': 50}
]>
```

Comment: Are you using `mysqlclient` or `mysql-python` or any other to connect to database?

Comment: @ilyasbbu using MySQL Connector/Python from MySQL community

Comment: @ilyasbbu I found that this is because that the mysql is using UTC but my TIME_ZONE is set to 'America/Los_Angeles'. It works if I change the TIME_ZONE to 'UTC' or filter with `date=TruncDate('created_at', tzinfo='UTC')`. Not sure how Django handles it internally...

Comment: @MasZero You can change TZ setting in settings.py file in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, Try this way:

```
qs = Data.objects.annotate(sum=Sum('number')).annotate(created_at__date=TruncDate('created_at')).values("created_at__date","sum")
```

Comment: I believe you are using timezone as 'UTC'? I need to use `date=TruncDate('created_at', tzinfo='UTC')` to get the date correctly. And it is not documentated yet:(

Comment: I prefer you to use mysqlclient to conect to database, it solves many issues like these